# Android - Database insert not inserting

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am including a database in my Android application. I am following the guide here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

I have a "DatabaseHelper" class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` as suggested, and I have a Contract that holds the information about the table and implements 'BaseColumns'. Therein, I have a function for inserting a new row into the database:

```
public static void addUploadInfo(SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper, UploadInfo info) {
    // Gets the data repository in write mode
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = info.getContentValues();

    // Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
    long newRowId;
    newRowId = db.insert(
            UploadInfoTable.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            values);

    db.close(); // Closing database connection

    info.setDatabaseId(newRowId);
}
```

I am using the database to store app related meta data about a file. When I create a new file, I run the above function, and a row is successfully added to the database (and the database is created successfully if needed). I can see it using:

```
public static List<UploadInfo> getUploadInfoList(SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper) {
    List<UploadInfo> infoList = new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String allQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + UploadInfoTable.TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(allQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            infoList.add(new UploadInfo(cursor));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return infoList;
}
```

However, when the app first loads, I insert a few initial entries into the database using:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    for (UploadInfo info: uploadList) {
        UploadInfoTable.addUploadInfo(dbHelper, info);
    }
}
```

These entries are assigned a new row ID that appears to be the correct value (not -1 indicating an error). There are no errors in the log. However, they are not found when I next run `getUploadInfoList`.

I have also tried this alternate insert function:

```
public static void addUploadInfo(SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper, UploadInfo info) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = info.getContentValues();

    // Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
    db.beginTransaction();
    long newRowId = -1;
    try {
        newRowId = db.insertOrThrow(
                UploadInfoTable.TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                values);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }

    db.close(); // Closing database connection

    info.setDatabaseId(newRowId);
}
```

but I see the same result. In no case is info null. I always log the contents of the `ContentValues`. I use final variables for column names, so don't think I have an error in column name. This would show up as a row value of -1 anyway, and it doesn't.

Why would one implementation of the code insert successfully and the other not?

Comment: Are you deleting the records `onPause()`?

Comment: @gknicker No, I only delete records on user action. The above `onResume` is a simplification, and only adds records if the user is upgrading from a previous system.

Comment: Ah ok. In that case I suspect your upgrade logic. Side note: it seems like `onCreate()` or `onStart()` would be a better place for your code.

Comment: The code I have in `onUpgrade` is simply to do a "DROP TABLE", and then "CREATE TABLE". Nothing more. Side note: You are right, this initialisation code should be `onCreate`, but I wouldn't think that would create the issue..? @gknicker

Comment: Why not just put all of the logic in `onUpgrade` rather than trying to detect the upgrade in `onResume`?

Comment: I am doing that as we speak. It does make sense. @gknicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your code in `onResume()` is not successfully detecting the upgrade. Rather put all your code having to do with the upgrade in `onUpgrade()` instead of trying to detect an upgrade in `onResume()`. That should resolve the issue.

Comment: Switching to use `onUpgrade` (or `onCreate`) has made the difference. I don't really understand why, but there must have been an issue with my logic. Thanks.